# Controller value is not populated properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Anything I am writing in my controller is not reflected in the HTML. 
I removed everything else in my code and just tried to render a simple message, but that, too, is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="Style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="app/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="mainApp">
    <div>
        <div ng-controller="MainCnt">
            <h1>
                {{message}}
            </h1>
        </div>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the JS part:

```
(function() {
    var main = angular.module("mainApp",[]);
    var MainController = function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello!";
    };
    main.controller = ("MainCnt",MainController);
}());
```

What am I doing wrong? Since the last hour I have not been able to show a simple message in my HTML. Instead it just shows `{{ message}}`.

Comment: HI, On console i am getting the below error message. Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ng/areq?p0=MainController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making an assignment in this line:

```
main.controller = ("MainCnt",MainController);
```

What you actually want to do is call the `controller()` method:

```
main.controller("MainCnt",MainController);
```

Comment: Thank you Sven. That was the problem. Its really silly.